# Understanding scrolling interactions in Chrome timeline

Tags: performance, google-chrome, animation, google-chrome-devtools

This is less a question about my specific problem than a question about some things in the Chrome performance timeline that I can't find documentation for, specifically: scroll interaction events.

Background: I'm troubleshooting a parallax animation that has some on-and-off jankiness. It uses a scroll handler to gather some information, and `requestAnimationFrame` to update styles. There's a clear pattern in the "Interaction" part of the timeline for "janky" vs. "not janky" frames, but I have little idea what these timeline events represent.

Here's a janky frame:

[image: janky frame]

Here's a smooth frame:

[image: good frame]

My JS code to make visual changes is triggered on `requestAnimationFrame`. My takeaways:

- It janks when that code aligns directly with the start of the frame, but not when it's towards the end of a frame (which seems to contradict what `requestAnimationFrame` is about?)
- It janks when the `Latency::ScrollUpdate` event continues past the end of the "Scroll Update" event. (As far as I can tell, `Latency::ScrollUpdate` is related to the presence of the scroll event handler.) This seems to be the crux of the issue—what does this situation mean?

What do the following "Interactions" events represent?

- **Scroll**: thin purple line at top
- **Scroll Update**: purple "Rendering" event
- **Latency::ScrollUpdate**: gray "System" event